# How do you say "ball of foot" in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary

[image]

I looked up it was 跖球, But I think it's a medical vocabulary.
Is there more popular word?

PS: Why is it called a ball?

Comment: I guess......前脚掌？

Comment: 脚掌前部，re：前脚 bkrs：（Ru）1)foreleg （兽）前腿
2) one foot, with one foot（踏在前面的脚） the forward foot in a step，
3) front part of foot
4) （与 “后脚”连用，表示时间靠近）no sooner ... than; the moment (when) ...; hardly ... when:
你前脚走，她后脚就到了。 She arrived the moment you had left.
    also 前臂, 手指头肚儿 inner side of the fingertip

Comment: In what context would you say “ball of foot” in Chinese? Would you have some examples of what you’re trying to convey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ball-of-foot):

> ball of foot n.
>   The padded portion of the sole of the human foot between the toes and the arch, on which the weight of the body rests when the heel is raised.

To find the proper translation of "balls of feet", I looked for articles discussing this mostly in context of proper running techniques, and jump roping.
Sites used: [(1)](https://read01.com/yPPJ7P.html#.WvCdR6QvyUk), [(2)](https://www.ettoday.net/news/20150527/511375.htm), [(3)](http://tw.gigacircle.com/1510682-1), [(4)](http://hk.running.biji.co/index.php?q=news&act=info&id=319&subtitle=%E8%B7%91%E6%AD%A5%E6%99%82%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E8%90%BD%E5%9C%B0%EF%BC%9F%E8%85%B3%E8%B7%9F%E8%88%87%E8%85%B3%E6%8E%8C%E7%9A%84%E8%BF%B7%E6%80%9D), [(5)](http://hk.running.biji.co/index.php?q=news&act=info&id=511&subtitle=%E5%A2%9E%E5%8A%A0%E5%8B%95%E8%83%BD%E6%B8%9B%E5%B0%91%E8%B2%A0%E8%8D%B7%20%E5%BE%9E%E5%8A%9B%E5%AD%B8%E7%9C%8B%E5%89%8D%E6%8E%8C%E8%91%97%E5%9C%B0), [(6)](https://www.wukong.com/question/6499281101633093901/), [(7)](https://fitz.hk/sports/running/%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%B8%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6-%E8%B7%91%E6%AD%A5%E8%90%BD%E8%85%B3%EF%BC%8C%E8%85%B3%E5%B0%96%E3%80%81%E8%85%B3%E6%8E%8C%E3%80%81%E8%85%B3%E8%B8%AD%E9%82%8A%E5%80%8B%E5%A5%BD/).

Conclusion:
"balls of feet" is typically referred to as 腳尖 and or 前腳掌.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult!

How about 脚球？（开玩笑）

The bones you are talking about are the 跖骨

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B7%96%E9%AA%A8/4055417?fr=aladdin

Can't really find a word for 'the ball of your foot', seems it is not a Chinese thing. The second joint of your thumb has no real common name in English either.